# python3 - edit value in YAML file in place

Tags: python, yaml

I am trying to use PyYAML and Python3 to edit values within a YAML file (it's a Hiera data structure, but that's a little beside the point).

It's easy enough to achieve with `yaml.safe_load` and `yaml.dump`.  The problem I have is that I need to preserve the comments, whitespace, ordering, and other formatting.  That is to say, when I edit the value for a given key, that should be the **only** change within the file.  (There is no requirement to add or remove keys themselves.)

In my case, these are second level keys.  I can do it with a regex or some form of state machine - but it's pretty nasty.  Is anyone aware of a library that does this neatly already?

Here's a dummied up example of the YAML concerned:

```
---
# Some form of comment block.
# Some form of comment block.
# Some form of comment block.

# This is my config block.
config::me:
  key0: 123
  key1: 456

# This is another config block:
applications:
  frontend:
    version: '2.4.2'
    enabled: true
  backend:
    version: '4.3.9'
    enabled: false

# More comments etcetera.
```

Essentially what I need to be able to do is target `applications.frontent.version` and update the value from `2.4.2` to `2.4.3` without touching **anything** else in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ruamel.yaml`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml/) for this which is a derivative of PyYAML ¹. It was especially created to do this kind of round-tripping, preserving comments, and several other things from the original file, that most parsers discard of during round-tripping (it is also YAML 1.2 compatible, whereas PyYAML supports 1.1)

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.util import load_yaml_guess_indent
from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import SingleQuotedScalarString

ys = """\
---
# Some form of comment block.
# Some form of comment block.
# Some form of comment block.

# This is my config block.
config::me:
  key0: 123
  key1: 456

# This is another config block:
applications:
  frontend:
    version: '2.4.2'
    enabled: true
  backend:
    version: '4.3.9'
    enabled: false

# More comments etcetera.
"""

data, indent, block_seq_indent = load_yaml_guess_indent(ys, preserve_quotes=True)
data['applications']['frontend']['version'] = SingleQuotedScalarString('2.4.3')
ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data, sys.stdout, explicit_start=True)
```

gives you:

```
---
# Some form of comment block.
# Some form of comment block.
# Some form of comment block.

# This is my config block.
config::me:
  key0: 123
  key1: 456

# This is another config block:
applications:
  frontend:
    version: '2.4.3'
    enabled: true
  backend:
    version: '4.3.9'
    enabled: false

# More comments etcetera.
```

The `preserve_quotes` option and use of `SingleQuotedScalarString()` are only necessary because you have quotes around the scalars `2.4.3` and `4.3.9` that are superfluous and would normally be dropped.

---

¹ <sub>Disclaimer: I am the author of `ruamel.yaml`.</sub>

Comment: Oooo.  I actually looked at that.  But I hadn't quite twigged that it preserved things quite so verbatim.  I will have look shortly and report back!  FWIW, the quotes around the scalars is because we also have version numbers that are of the form 201612012359 which end up casted to int by Puppet if not quoted.  So it's easiest just to give people a consistent direction.

Comment: Well, you're just all kinds of awesome.  And we'll leave it at that!  Thanks for you help (and the library).